# Previous tenant did some shoddy DIY, should we be concerned?

Tags: plumbing, wire, hole

Not a typical DIY question, but I was hoping some people here could help us out.

The previous tenant did some construction work that seems sketchy at best. (Pics below)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/irgM6.jpg

He actually moved the hot water heater across the apartment and ran the hot and cold water pipes underneath and in the top of the radiator. There are also holes in walls and exposed wires and pipes coming from them.

Should we be concerned about the work he did, and if so, what steps could be taken to try and fix what he did? We feel it's currently unsafe and really need some advice!!

Comment: When you say "previous tenant", are you renting, or do you own?

Comment: We are renting. We moved into this apartment and now we're starting to find all these other issues

Comment: Did the landlord sign off on the work? Or did the tenant just do it of his/her own accord? Either way I'm seeing some real red flags here in terms of how the property is managed.

Comment: At this point, we don't know. The contractors who were here to replace our moldy kitchen counter told us about the work the previous tenant did. He also installed a sleeping loft that has held up fine (so far) but creaks quite a bit with people up there

Comment: Although absolutely shoddy looking, it doesn't seem particularly unsafe; provided those black cables aren't 120v. What is that uncapped pipe doing sticking up in the air? Pictures of the reinstalled equipment would possibly alleviate *my* concerns.

Comment: We _think_ the uncapped pipe is from when the water heater used to be installed in the closet, but haven't wanted to move or fool with it yet. And does the fact that these holes open straight into the wall/brick exterior cause safety issues? Obviously we don't know about heating issues yet, but we had no problems air conditioning the space during the summer.

Comment: those "random wires in a box" are phone lines. the connectors on them are called scotch-locks.

Answer (score 2):

That was not previous tenant work. That was shoddy handyman work over a long period of time. I'd venture to bet it was the LL himself trying to save money.

Bottom line is: You CANNOT do ANY electrical work in a place that you are renting (if that's what you are asking). Your only recourse is to contact the LL and tell him about it and ask him to make the repairs corrections, or have it done by someone. Than again, from the looks of it I bet he already knows and does not care. I'm curious, did you not see any of this before you signed the lease??

The wiring shown is phone wire and poses no safety hazard. Unless of course you are holding bare wires when the phone rings. Then you'll get a small shock.

Comment: We did not see any of this before signing the lease. Part of this was naivety on our part (e.g. the pipe running over and under the radiator). However one of the holes pictured is in the corner of the closet, and the other partially hidden by the box covering the hot water heater. As commented on my original post, we believe the previous tenant made these changes to accommodate the sleeping loft we believe he built

Comment: Well, like I said, from the looks of that piping, etc, that's all been like that for many years. With the exception of the new spray foam.

Comment: That makes sense, since the pipe insulation is disintegrating on the bottom. There is an additional pipe shoved into the top of the radiator too, with much newer pipe insulation. Is that normal?

Comment: "Normal" doesn't much matter when renting. If it isn't dangerous, and doesn't violate codes, and works, it's the owner's problem.